# how to determine if difference between two values falls within range with awk?

Tags: awk

If I have the `input`:

```
0
5
7
13
```

I want to calculate the difference between the values for each subsequent line. I have done so with:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$1;next}{print $1-x;x=$1}'
```

This will generate:

```
5
2
6
```

My struggle is that I want to print a `+` sign beside the output value if the two numbers used to calculate it (from the `input` file) encompass values from `6-8`. So I would get the following output:

```
5 -
2 +
6 +
```

The `2` and `6` will have a `+` sign beside it because the two values (`5` and `7` and `7` and `13`) that were used to calculate them contain value between `6-8`.

Please let me know if any clarification is necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same idea as the above `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$1;next} 
            {print $1-p, 
             ((p-6)*(p-8)<=0 || ($1-6)*($1-8)<=0)?"+":"-"; p=$1}' file

5 -
2 +
6 +
```

ps.  This checks whether at least one of the values is between the 6,8 range.  If you want both change `||` with `&&`.

UPDATE:  The range check should be based on the span of the two entries as explained in the comments.  This should do:

```
$ awk 'function max(x,y) {return x>y?x:y}; 
       function min(x,y) {return x>y?y:x}; 
       NR==1{p=$1;next} {print $1-p,
               (max($1,p)<6 || min($1,p)>8)?"-":"+"; p=$1}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However when I run this on the values `0 4 10 11`, I get `4- 6- 1-` where I should get `4- 6+ 1-` since `4` and `10` encompass `6` and `8`. The only difference here is that `4` and `10` include both `6` and `8`. I get the same result when using @F.Knorr answer.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you meant.  See the update.

Answer (score 3):

All you need are some additional checks, if I understand you correctly:

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$1;next}
          {sign = (x >= 6 && x <= 8) || ($1 >= 6 && $1 <= 8) ? "+" : "-"
           print $1-x" "sign;x=$1}' test
```

Output:

```
5 -
2 +
6 +
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does indeed work. However, if I try it with a different set of values: `0 4 10 11`, I get the following output: `4- 6+ 1+`. The `1` should have a `-` beside it because `10` and `11` don't contain `6` to `8`. Any further advice?

Comment: I think the typo is `x <= $1`, should be `$1<=8`

Comment: Yes, I had a little error in the last comparison. I have edited and corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice. I like to write that like this: `(6 <= $1 && $1 <= 8)` -- I think that reads more "mathematically"